# How do I get rid of dimming when playing youtube video?

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube

I'm using the following code to launch a youtube video.  It works great except that every 30 seconds the screen goes dim.  Tapping the screen brightens it again (and also brings up the video controls as expected.)  This happens even if I have auto-lock turned off for my iPod touch.  What is going on?

```
NSString* embeddedCode =@"<html><body bgcolor='#008080'><center><iframe width='212' height='172' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEOID]?rel=0' frameborder='0'></iframe><p style='color: yellow;'>YouTube Video</p><p style='color: yellow;'>(Requires Internet access.)</p></center><body></html>";    
UIWebView* videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,350)]; 
[videoView loadHTMLString:embeddedCode baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the section of code where I'm deliberately dimming the screen.  Just don't want to do that in this case.